How to calculate the quasi-component?
Question:X={$0,1$}×{$0$}$∪[0,1]
×${$\frac{1}{n}:n∈\mathbb{N}$} with the subspace topology $$  from $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathscr{T}_{\mathbb{R}^2})$. Find its components and quasi-components.

My progress:

Some little trouble about the former: I know the point {$0$}× {$0$} is connected as the point space. But, how can I show that it's a component?(i.e.show it is a maximal connected set containing it)
Quasi-component: How can I calculate the quasi-component?My thought is using the following proposition:


The quasi‑component of  in $(,)$ is the intersection of clopen subsets of  containing .

But I don't know the next step, could you give me some hint?

Definition : Let $p_0,p_1∈X$ for a topological space $(X,\mathscr{T})$. We say that $(X,\mathscr{T})$
is connected between p0
and $p_1$
if for every separation $U_0$
and $U_1$
of $(X,\mathscr{T})$
, either $U_0
⊇${$p_0,p_1
$} or $U_1
⊇${$p_0,p_1$
} ; such an equivalence class is a quasi‑component.

If I were given this problem, the first thing I would want to do is identify the non-empty clopen subsets of $X.$ Any that are minimal will be components of the space, and the rest will allow us to identify the quasicomponent of any point that doesn't lie in one of those components.
When I visualize this space, I imagine that it consists of two separated points on the $x$-axis, along with a countable set of closed horizontal line segments that get arbitrarily close to the $x$-axis (and to the $2$ points of $X$ lying on the axis).
I imagine that for each of the line segments, I can draw an open rectangle around it that contains no other point in the space except for the points of that segment, and such that no other point of the space is even on the boundary of the open box. Do you see how we might define such an open rectangle for any given segment?
The above actually lets me identify the connected component of almost every single point of $X.$ Do you see why?
The union of finitely-many of these connected components will therefore be clopen in $X,$ as will the complement of such a union. Do you see how to prove this?
I also notice that, no matter how small a circle I draw around one of the $2$ points on the $x$-axis, it will have points of infinitely-many of the segments inside of it. Given some $A\subseteq X$ such that $A$ contains one of the points of the $x$-axis, it can be shown that $A$ cannot be clopen if it fails to fully contain all but finitely-many of the segments. Put another way, suppose we define the segments by $$S_n:=[0,1]×\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}$$ for each positive integer $n,$ so that $$X=\bigl\{\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle\}\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n,$$ and suppose that $A$ is a clopen subset of $X$ such that $\langle x,0\rangle\in A$ for some $x\in\{0,1\}$ Then there are at most finitely-many positive integers $n$ for which $S_n\not\subseteq A.$ Can you tell from this what the clopen sets containing at least one point on the $x$-axis must be?
From this, can you determine the other (quasi)components?

Thank you for your help.I will try to answer you question:

“Any that are minimal will be components of the space”，I'm sorry,is it right?

"it can be shown that A cannot be clopen if it fails to fully contain all but finitely-many of the segments",I'm also confused with this.Maybe my english is bad,could you give me further expalnation?

Regarding your first question, it would have been more accurate to say "given any $A$ that is minimal among the non-empty clopen subsets of $X,$ we can readily show that $A$ is a component of $X.$"

Regarding your second question, perhaps it would make more sense to say that "If $A$ is a subset of $X$ that contains at least one of the two points on the $x$-axis, then in order for $A$ to be clopen, all except a finite number of the segments must be subsets of the set $A.$" Is that clearer?

One key observation is that if some clopen subset $A$ of $X$ contains at least one point of a segment $S_n:=[0,1]×\left{\frac{1}{n}\right},$ then $S_n$ must be a subset of $A.$ Can you prove this?

,ok,I totally understand your statements.Thank you for your help,I'm very thankful.

I'm sorry, maybe I don't know the proof,could you give me some hint?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
